# Installed Exe needs to add files to installation folder in Program Files

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, installshield, installshield-le

I tried building a setup for my .NET project using **InstallShield Limited Edition**.
The problem is my .EXE needs to download some extra DLLs and cache files and save them in same folder as EXE, but since the files are in `Program Files` folder the app has no permission to write.
When I run app having admin permissions it works.

Comment: Why not put them into the local app data folder ?

Comment: I need DLLs beside the app

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you really need to have .exe and .dll in the same folder. Normally it is not necessary to have them in the same location, so you could store the dll *and* the cache files in a directory that is accessible by normal (read: users without administrative permissions) users.

As an alternative you could install the whole application in such a directory, this would have the advantage that even for the initial install you don't need administrative permissions on the computer. And both .exe, .dll and cache files would be in the same directory.

Although it is not common to install programs outside the program files directory there is software that does so. Read about how Google installs Chrome: https://superuser.com/questions/592015/where-is-chrome-exe-in-windows-8